# How to save an NSMutableArray of images as a Photoshop file

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray, nsarray, photoshop

I found [Layers](http://www.layersforiphone.com) that will save the project as a Photoshop file that can be edited as Photoshop, but how do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sign up as a Photoshop developer at http://www.adobe.com/devnet/ and download and/or license the Photoshop file format specification.